# Is there a tool/function that can be used to compare patterns macro forms?

Tags: clojure

I use the `gensym` function in some of my macros which then makes it hard to test:

so the expansion of some macro might be:

```
'(let [G__10458 (js-obj)] 
   (aset G__10458 "a" (fn [] (? G__10458.val))) 
   (aset G__10458 "val" 3) G__10458)
```

what I want is to test that it matches up to this type of patten:

```
'(let [%1 (js-obj)] 
   (aset %1 "a" (fn [] (? %1.val))) 
   (aset %1 "val" 3) %1)
```

Is there something in the `clojure.core.match` library or another pattern matching library that does this?

Comment: First, write your macro without gensym. Keep updating and testing the macro until it's doing what you want. Finally, add gensym.

Comment: I know I can do that but it's not what I want

Comment: gensym is a tool to be used when your macro is already past the testing phase and you're putting it to real work. The whole reason gensym exists is to prevent naming collisions at run time, which is not a major concern when you're still building and testing the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rolled my own for now. It pattern matches on vectors, lists and hash-map vals (pattern matching on sets and hash-map keys are too hard for me right now).

```
(defn match-sym? [v]
  (and (symbol? v)
       (re-find #"^%" (str v))))

(defn match
  ([f1 f2] (match f1 f2 (atom {})))
  ([v1 v2 dict]
     (cond (or (and (list? v1) (list? v2))
            (and (vector? v1) (vector? v2)))
        (and (= (count v1) (count v2))
             (->> (map #(match %1 %2 dict) v1 v2)  
                  (every? true?)))

        (and (hash-map? v1) (hash-map? v2))
        (and (= (keys v1) (keys v2))
             (->> (map #(match %1 %2 dict) (vals v1) (vals v2))
                  (every? true)))

        (match-sym? v2)
        (if-let [vd (@dict v2)]
          (match v1 vd dict)
          (do (swap! dict assoc v2 v1)
              true))
        :else (= v1 v2))))
```

and its usage:

```
> (match '(1 1) '(1 1)) 
;=> true

> (match '(1 1) '(%1 %1)) 
;=> true

> (match '(1 2) '(%1 %1)) 
;=> false 

> (match '(let [x 1] (+ x 2))
         '(let [%x 1] (+ %x 2)))
;=> true

> (match '(let [G__42879 (js-obj)]
            (aset G__42879 "a" (fn [] (? G__42879.val)))
            (aset G__42879 "val" 3) G__42879)

         '(let [%x (js-obj)]
            (aset %x "a" (fn [] (? %x.val)))
            (aset %x "val" 3) %x))
;=> true
```

Comment: Nice, you can also do this and handle more cases with core.unify or with core.logic's simple unifier interface

Comment: Can you put up an example?

Answer (score 7):

Realistically testing the expansions of your macros is extremely brittle. If you go down that path, any little change in your macro will cause your tests to fail - even if your macro still does the same thing!

A better approach - IMO - is to test what your macro is supposed to do. We can safely assume that invoking your macro has an observable side effect - in your example it sets properties in a JS object.

In this case, instead of testing the expansion, I'd write a test that makes sure the state of the JS object is what you expect it to be after invoking your macro.

This decouples the test from the implementation, giving you freedom to refactor your macro as you see fit since the test is a lot more robust and will only fail if your macro actually does the wrong thing.

As a rule of thumb I'd never test the expansion of a macro.

Comment: I usually break my macro down into smaller functions so I'm really testing those smaller code generating functions. I find that its nicer to figure out what code its outputting first before reasoning about what it will do. And also in this case, its outputting clojurescript, which is really hard to test directly.

Comment: That's fair enough. However testing the expansion is still brittle so personally I wouldn't do it. To me, it's like testing that a `double` function works by making sure it invokes `*` with the argument and the number 2, whereas a perfectly valid implementation could just do `(+ argument argument)`. This would break your test, even though the output is exactly the same. Just my 2c.